# Is there a better way to resolve emacs lib dependency?

Tags: unit-testing, emacs, elisp, dependency-management, ert

I came across a problem when I tried to run the test files in a emacs project.

For example, I cloned [this project](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el) into my home directory, cd into test dir and then used `emacs -batch -l ert -l nrepl-tests.el -f ert-run-tests-batch-and-exit` to run the tests. But it couldn't locate the file nrepl.el which was not in the same directory. So, I copy one into ~/nrep.el/test. But it said "Cannot open load file: clojure-mode". That is the question I'm concered.

I do have clojure-mode and other libs nrepl.el use. But they are all in different directory(In my case, ~/emacs.d/packs/live/clojure-pack/lib/). Do I have to duplicate these files into my cloned nrepl project in order to run the test? Is there a better way to run test files like we do in IDE. For instance, in Intellij, I simply write import statements in test files, and it automatically prepares the dependency libs for me. This bothers me quite a lot. I'm wondering if there is a best practice for this problem.

Comment: You should probably just use the provided `Makefile` to run the tests.  In it the author did all the hard work of building the correct `load-path`.

Comment: @lunaryorn That's right. I forgot the Makefile. It seems I will have to learn some make instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I'm under impression that [Carton](https://github.com/rejeep/carton) is precisely what you're looking for to overcome these dependency issues: package maintainer is expected to write a small file containing package dependencies including development ones, like ert, and run emacs via `carton exec` which will make sure everything is downloaded to a certain directory and this directory is added to `load-path`.